# Audio Output in Jade

Tags: html, node.js, audio, pug, backend

I am new to using Jade.js and the documentation hasn't been very helpful. I would really appreciate it if someone linked me to an elaborate documentation and shows me how to do the following html code in Jade.js. Thanks for all the help in advance!

```
<audio controls autoplay>
   <source src="screamer.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try here: http://jade-lang.com/demo/

Its also possible to convert html into jade: http://html2jade.org/

Your html can be produced by this snippet

```
audio(controls='', autoplay='')
  source(src='screamer.wav', type='audio/mpeg')
```